# Оpen source solution to manage and store project info? And view it like cards

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, project-management, document-management

We have a list of our projects in an Excel file, we now want it to be managed in a more convenient way, where all employees would have access to it using their browser.

Projects have atributes: client, manager name, price, status, etc. We also have different types of project documentation and need to upload these files to the projects.

I looked through lots of project managers I found in the web but no one seems to suit our requirements. Many CMS's are more complicated than we need.

Maybe I was looking on wrong resources but I haven't even come up with the name to what I am actually looking for.

If you know anything that would suit please name it, or maybe help formulate the name of such a system.

We look for these features:

- web-interface
- add/edit/delete the project
- upload multiple files for each project
- search
- project status
- user access settings

Preferrably php/mysql, I am looking only for open source software.

Answer (score 2):

You could give Kanban Boards a try. 
You could create for each project a board and store the different types of information on cards.

Maybe you can use Trello (Web Software). Trello provides some examples at https://trello.com/inspiration

Or you use a open source Kanban Board like https://wekan.github.io/